# Error when running OpenGL application in Cygwin: GLXBadFBConfig

Tags: opengl, cygwin, x11

I'm running a demo program in Cygwin/X with glew and freeglut. The program requests OpenGL 3.3. I received this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  386
  Current serial number in output stream:  385
```

When *exporting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose*, it returned as below:

```
libGL: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
libGL: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
libGL: enabled GLX_MESA_swap_control
libGL: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
libGL: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample
libGL: enabled GLX_SGIS_multisample
libGL: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
libGL: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
libGL: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  386
  Current serial number in output stream:  385
```

I'm running the program in a Xterm, which is started with the environment

```
export LIBGL_USE_WGL=1
```

*glewinfo | grep OpenGL* returns as below:

```
OpenGL version 4.5.13397 Compatibility Profile Context 15.200.1046.0 is supported
```

But if I use Mesa, it only supports OpenGL 3.0.

I specify the OpenGL version using

```
glutInitContexVersion(3, 3)
```

, and the version string in GLSL shader is

```
#version 330
```

I have upgraded all the drivers installed in Windows.

This program runs well under a SDK provided [here](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/glsdk/index.html) without glew and it uses the SDK to load OpenGL functions. But I want it running without the SDK, so I use glew.

I want to run this program in Windows, so I want to keep using Cygwin/X. Do I have to install some extra Cygwin packages or configure the Cygwin/X with some extra parameters?

Comment: Do you have an Intel GPU? My 10.5 Mesa on a i5 with HD5500 won't support OpenGL 3.3 in a compatibility profile, only a core. Have you tried adding glutIntContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE)?

Comment: @HughFisher No, I use AMD Radeon HD 7660G. And I have already specified a core profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try there is running OpenGL using GLX through the Cygwin X11 server. The Cygwin X.org on Windows GDI server does simply not support the OpenGL profile you requested.

When it comes to APIs for accessing GPUs you should always use a *native* port, which in your case means, linking against the plain Windows opengl32.lib (instead of libGL.so of Cygwin) and using a build of FreeGLUT and GLEW that uses WGL instead of GLX.

The easiest way to do that would be not using Cygwin, but MinGW.